# What are some examples of vector spaces that aren't graded?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_vector_space): a vector space $V$ is graded if it decomposes into direct sum $ \oplus_{n \geq 0} V_n$ of vector spaces $V_n$.

So as far as I understand things, any vector space with a countable basis is graded:  Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$ with basis $\{v_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then $V = \oplus_{n\geq 0} k\cdot v_n$.  Then the only vector spaces that I can think of that aren't *obviously* graded are things like $C(X)$, the space of continuous functions on some manifold $X$

Is this correct? are there any more? or do I not understand something?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Grading isn't a property of a vector space: it's extra *structure* attached to a vector space, in the same way that a multiplication is an extra structure you attach to a set to make it a group. So this is a little like asking "what are some examples of sets that aren't groups?" (As it turns out, every set can be equipped with a group structure, and this is equivalent to the axiom of choice. But this is missing the point.)

Every vector space admits a trivial grading in which $V_0 = V$ and $V_n = 0$ for all $n \ge 1$. But we often encounter vector spaces (such as the space of polynomials) with *natural* gradings, they are usually nontrivial, and taking advantage of this extra structure is useful in various ways.

Comment: well that certainly clears things up.  thanks!